# TSQL Prevent SQL injection on SPROC with a WHERE clause as parameter

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection, where-clause

I am currently developing an application that *MUST* select several different tables whose results are interconnected. The return data will be saved in a .NET DataSet object in the client application.

The input variables of the stored procedure need to be the where clause of the select statement. This is a requirement of the business logic, since the application must allow such advanced searches.

What I wanted to make is a stored procedure (because of the need to return more than one table that are connected to each other and whose results are inter-dependent) that would have WHERE clauses that would be appended to a dynamic SQL such as:

```
create procedure up_test (
    @input varchar(255)
) as

    EXEC( 'SELECT * FROM person.person ' + @input)


go
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input for the SP has to be the where clause for a select statement then there is no way you can prevent sql injection.

One of the reasons is that it opens the door to people closing the select statement and then writing whatever else they want, updates, deletes, you name it.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to only allow certain verbs in the EXEC statement? If I could allow only SELECT to the EXEC, it should work, I guess...

Comment: Not 100% sure but I also believe it is. You can hack something together like raising exceptions when a `;` is passed as the where clause but still, that only goes so far. Such a "solution" might also raise exceptions for legit statements.

Comment: It is true, this is not the way to go.